# Bulk Records Insert in Python and Oracle DB SQL

Tags: python, sql, bulkinsert

I am trying to do insert bulk records but before that I have sql query to pull records from different table.
Records size is around 4.5 millions and on that I am running query results set in Python loop and inserting one by one in oracle database. Its taking around 17 hours to complete the whole process.

Below is the highlight of the process.

I am running first query to get the `record_number` from the first table, let say below is the query.

```
query = "SELECT record_number FROM descriptions"
cursor.execute(query)
```

Above table fetching 4.5 million records.

After that I am running Python loop to run with each `record_number` and again running one SQL select query to pull some other details from other tables where I am passing each `record_number`.

```
for record_number_val in cursor.fetchall():
       SELECT NVL( nvl((SELECT SUM(NVL(cost, 0))  
       FROM table1 WHERE record_number =record_number_val   ), 0) + nvl((SELECT SUM(NVL(cost, 0))  FROM table2 
       WHERE record_number = record_number_val ), 0), 0) FROM dual
```

Basically we are adding cost details from two different tables by passing record number.
After that we run one insert query in loop to add `record_number`, `cost` to a new table for ex. `table3`.

```
query= "INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (val1, cost, record_number)
```

I am looking for better solution to dump this records in quickest possible way in this scenario.

Comment: Why loop in Python instead of one insert in Oracle? Something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bq8gZdFc).

Comment: I have tried that solution but even in that case it'll take hours to insert 4.5 Million records in `table3`.
I have tested with 1000 records only and it took approx. 17 seconds.

Comment: I hope you have indexes on table1(record_number) and table2(record_number). Please check how long this query works: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bux8uuQq).

Comment: Its taking **2.5** seconds to gives result in `SQL developer` as well as Python `fetchall()`

Comment: So counting rows from other tables is fast. Even on my old laptop insert-select of 5 mln rows takes no longer than minutes. I don't know what can be the reason why it is so slow. I can only advise to do it on DB if possible, surely not in loop row by row.

Comment: Hi @PonderStibbons 
Earlier I assumed that indexing was there in table but I ran the execution plan with plan table output and found that query is not using Indexes (There was no indexes). Now I am able to dump 4.5 million records in approx. 15 minutes instead of 17 hours.

Thanks for helping me out